# Visual Studio code font is very thin in the editor in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: visual-studio-code

Fonts in my vs code editor appears very thin compared to that of atom or vs code in windows. I have tried many settings but none worked. Here is a sample code in c++.
[image: Click to see sample code in C++,even datatypes like int is not getting bold]
[image: Click to see fonts in setting.json page]

Answer (score 3):

The same happens to me. Try whit the following in settings.json (Ctrl + ,):

```
"editor.fontFamily":"'monospace'"
```